# Ext.draw.container can't load in Ext.JS 6.5.1 and newer versions

Tags: javascript, extjs

A simple example,

```
Ext.define('TestExample.view.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.draw.Container',
alias: 'viewmodel.schedule'
...
});
```

causes a "[E] [Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load"

because the class is Ext.draw.Container (It loads with any other class I've tried)

To confirm the problem, see eg https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.draw.Container.html

and click the run button- it fails! Try the same in version 6.2.0, and it works!

Anyone know about this bug in the newer versions?

Comment: The bug in the 6.5.1 docs is fixed by adding a newline at the end of the sample code.